# SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<T0020
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.safersys.org/namespaces/T0020V1 T0020V1.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.safersys.org/namespaces/T0020V1">
    <INTERFACE>
        <NAME>SAFER</NAME>
        <VERSION>04.02</VERSION>
    </INTERFACE>
    <TRANSACTION>
        <VERSION>01.00</VERSION>
        <OPERATION>REPLACE</OPERATION>
        <DATE_TIME>2009-09-01T00:00:00</DATE_TIME>
        <TZ>CT</TZ>
    </TRANSACTION>
    <IRP_ACCOUNT>
        <IRP_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER>564182</IRP_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER>
        <IRP_BASE_COUNTRY>US</IRP_BASE_COUNTRY>
        <IRP_BASE_STATE>AR</IRP_BASE_STATE>
        <IRP_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>67432</IRP_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
        <IRP_ACCOUNT_TYPE>I</IRP_ACCOUNT_TYPE>
        <IRP_STATUS_CODE>100</IRP_STATUS_CODE>
        <IRP_STATUS_DATE>2008-02-01</IRP_STATUS_DATE>
        <IRP_UPDATE_DATE>2009-06-18</IRP_UPDATE_DATE>
        <IRP_NAME>
            <NAME_TYPE>LG</NAME_TYPE>
            <NAME>LARRY SHADDON</NAME>
            <IRP_ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS_TYPE>PH</ADDRESS_TYPE>
                <STREET_LINE_1>10291 HWY 124</STREET_LINE_1>
                <STREET_LINE_2/>
                <CITY>RUSSELLVILLE</CITY>
                <STATE>AR</STATE>
                <ZIP_CODE>72802</ZIP_CODE>
                <COUNTY>POPE</COUNTY>
                <COLONIA/>
                <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            </IRP_ADDRESS>
            <IRP_ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS_TYPE>MA</ADDRESS_TYPE>
                <STREET_LINE_1>10291 HWY124</STREET_LINE_1>
                <STREET_LINE_2/>
                <CITY>RUSSELLVILLE</CITY>
                <STATE>AR</STATE>
                <ZIP_CODE>72802</ZIP_CODE>
                <COUNTY>POPE</COUNTY>
                <COLONIA/>
                <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            </IRP_ADDRESS>
        </IRP_NAME>
    </IRP_ACCOUNT>
</T0020>
```

I am using following XSLT to split my xml file to multiple xml file .

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.safersys.org/namespaces/T0020V1" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml" /> 
 <xsl:variable name="accounts" select="t:T0020/t:IRP_ACCOUNT" /> 
 <xsl:variable name="size" select="30" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$accounts[position() mod $size = 1]">
   <xsl:variable name="filename" select="resolve-uri(concat('output/',position(),'.xml'))" /> 
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" method="xml">
     <T0020>
      <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::t:IRP_ACCOUNT[position() &lt; $size]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="." /> 
        </xsl:for-each>      
     </T0020>
    </xsl:result-document>    
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works well in Sample Java Apllication,but when i tried to use same in my Spring based application then it gives following error .

```
Error on line 1 column 1 of T0020:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I don't know what goes wrong ? Please help me. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What is the XML you are transforming?

Comment: Can i edit question as another problem I am facing with xslt should I include in this or write separate question?

Comment: Erm... if Larry Shaddon is a real person you probably want to remove his details from here, and from the stylusstudio forum you posted on.

Comment: hi Brabster,Can you please elaborate ? I am not getting your point ?Should i post the question ?

Comment: @Nisarg: Welcome to SO!  If your other problem is not closely related to this one, you should submit it as a separate question.  Brabster was saying that you should remove the personal information from your post; if Larry is a real person, he might not appreciate having his address posted publicly.  You can do this with the edit link under your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot Torgamus,now i understood what Brabster wants to say.Ok i will ask seprate one.

Answer (score 5):

Your XML starts with a **byte-order mark** in UTF-8 (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF), which isn't visible. Try opening your file with a hex editor and have a look.

Many text editors under Windows like to insert this at the start of UTF-8 encoded text, despite the fact that UTF-8 doesn't actually *need* a byte order mark since the ordering of bytes in UTF-8 is already well defined.

Java's XML parsers will all choke on a BOM with exactly the error message you are seeing. You'll need to either strip out the BOM, or write a wrapper for your InputStream that you're handing the XML parser to do this for you at parsing time.

Answer (score 1):

There is some content in the document before the XML data starts, probably whitespace at a guess (that's where I've seen this before).

The prolog is the part of the document that is before the opening tag, with tag-like constructs like `<?` and `<!`. You may have some characters/whitespace in between these tags too. Prologs and valid content are explained on [tiztag.com](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlprolog.php).

Maybe post up an depersonalised example of your XML data?

Comment: It was problem while doing Transformation and now its Resolved .Thanks a lot for Respose.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to get this if you attempt to process the content twice. (Which is fairly easy to do in spring.) In which case, there'd be nothing wrong with your XML. This scenario seems likely since the sample application works, but introducing spring causes problems.

Comment: Thanks My Problem is solved,its kind of Transformation problem with Spring .It is resolved thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `encoding="UTF-16"` was causing this issue. It got resolved when I changed it to `UTF-8`.